# In-App Purchase: Consumable or Non-Consumable?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing an iPhone app which is related to books.

I have 5 books in my app. User will be able to purchase just one book at a time or all 5 books in one shot. One book costs 1.99$ and 5 books cost 7.99$

I think I've got to set the 5 books purchase as non-consumable and the 1 book purchase as consumable. Am I right?

In iTunes connect, should I set them as consumables or non-consumables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumables are things that get used up, like extra ammunition or spendable "points" in games like Farmville. Your books will not be consumed and cease to exist, so no, consumable isn't the correct category for your purchases.